# Is this an acceptable comment?

Tags: discussion

> The down vote is because you answered a question Bob a/k/a Ben Rutgers a/k/a user50888 also answered. Competing answers to questions Ben, err, I mean Bob, has answered are frequently downvoted. For the past several months, every single answer I've posted to a question that has also been answered by Bob (either before or after I answered it) has received at least one downvote.

Comment: Could you please link to the question and/or answer where this occurred?

Comment: https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/124452/15871

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to give a somewhat generalised answer here:

- [Systematic downvoting is not acceptable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me).
- If you believe systematic downvoting is occurring, the correct way to handle this is to not to post a forcefully worded comment, but instead to flag posts for moderator attention. While moderators have no ability to see individual votes, we will escalate serious issues to Stack Exchange staff to investigate.
- If comments are posted which do not further the Stack Exchange goal of building [a community that is rooted in kindness, collaboration, and mutual respect](https://photo.stackexchange.com/conduct), the correct way to handle this is not to post a passive-aggressive question on Meta, but instead to flag the comment for moderator attention.

Even more generally, I would request that everybody involved here takes some time to re-read the [Code of Conduct](https://photo.stackexchange.com/conduct) and to try and modify their future actions so that incidents like this can be avoided. Thank you.

Comment: "They deserved it" is the *sine qua non* of bullying. Two of your three bullet points indicate your support of the cyber bulling.

Comment: The comment was flagged for moderator attention. It was swept under the rug as seems to be SOP.

Comment: If you believe I have committed a code of conduct violation please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is, no. Comments like that are not in accordance with the Code of Conduct.